# CRC32 - wrong checksum using TABLE algorithm and 04C11DB7 polynomial

Tags: c, crc, crc32

I am following a painless guide to code correction algorithms. (https://zlib.net/crc_v3.txt) I've managed to write a TABLE algorithm, using extra loop for augmented part (I hope so). I am trying to write a most widely used CRC32 version (with 0x04C11DB7 polynomial), but I can not get the right CRC value.

I've achieved the correct table for CRC32 values with mentioned polynomial.
My code for generating CRC32 (chapter 9 and 10):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CRC32_BYTE_POSSIBLE_VALUES 255
#define CRC32_LAST_BIT_MASK 0x80000000

#define CRC32_POLYNOMIAL 0x04C11DB7

uint32_t __crc32_table[CRC32_BYTE_POSSIBLE_VALUES] = { 0 };

void __crc32_fill_crc_table() {
    uint32_t reg;
    uint8_t byte = 0;

    for (;;) {
        reg = (byte << 24);

        for (uint8_t byte_size = 0; byte_size < 8; byte_size++) {
            if (reg & CRC32_LAST_BIT_MASK) {
                reg <<= 1;
                reg ^= CRC32_POLYNOMIAL;
            } else {
                reg <<= 1;
            }
        }

        __crc32_table[byte] = reg;
        if (byte == 255)
            break;
        else
            byte++;
    }

}

void __crc32_print_table(uint32_t *arr) {
    printf(" 0x%08X ", arr[0]);

    for (uint32_t i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        if (!(i % 8))
            printf("\n");

        printf(" 0x%08X ", arr[i]);

    }

    printf("\n");
}

uint8_t inverse_byte(uint8_t byte) {
    uint8_t reflected_byte = 0;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (byte & (1 << i))
            reflected_byte |= (1 << (7 - i));
    }

    return reflected_byte;
}

uint32_t inverse(uint32_t src) {

    uint32_t toret;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if (src & (1 << i))
            toret |= (1 << (31 - i));
    }

    return toret;
}


uint32_t __crc32_table_approach( unsigned char *data, size_t size) {
    uint32_t reg = -1;
    uint8_t top_byte;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        top_byte = (uint8_t)(reg >> 24);
        reg = (reg << 8) | inverse_byte(data[i]);
        reg ^= __crc32_table[top_byte];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        top_byte = (uint8_t) (reg >> 24);
        reg = (reg << 8) ;
        reg ^= __crc32_table[top_byte];
    }

    return inverse(reg) ^ -1;
}

uint32_t calc_crc32(unsigned char *data, size_t size) {
    if (!__crc32_table[1])
        __crc32_fill_crc_table();

    __crc32_print_table(__crc32_table);

    return __crc32_table_approach(data, size);
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    
    unsigned char* test = "123456789";
    size_t test_len = strlen(test);

    uint32_t crc = calc_crc32(test, test_len);
    printf("CRC32: 0x%08X", crc);
    return 0;
}
```

The inverse function reverses bits of UINT32 value, and function inverse_byte inverses bits of UINT8 value.

But for the '123456789' string I get the wrong checksum.
Could someone help me? Or give some advice?

---

Input string: '123456789'

Outputted CRC: CRC32: 0x22016B0A

Desired CRC: CRC32: 0xCBF43926

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including a complete runnable program, sample input that reproduces the problem, the observed output, and the desired output.

Comment: Added repository with example.

Comment: It looks like the guide says to initialize the register with `0`, and you are initializing it with `-1`. Did you do that in purpose?

Comment: As far as I know, the most known CRC32 uses init value 0xFFFFFFFF for the register, and also reflects in/out data with final XOR. Later in this document these characteristics are noted (REFIN/REFOUT etc.).

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre] entirely inside the question. External links may be used for supplementary information, but all information, including code, necessary to reproduce the problem should be inside the post itself. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service. It exists to provide a durable repository of questions and answers for other people to use in the future. Files at external links change or vanish over time and so are not suitable for recording questions.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. All-in-one source file included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made your array one word too short, and so overwrote the allocated memory. It needs to be:

```
#define CRC32_BYTE_POSSIBLE_VALUES 256
```

Though that part probably still worked, because C.

You need to initialize the variable you are reversing into:

```
    uint32_t toret = 0;
```

These lines:

```
    top_byte = (uint8_t)(reg >> 24);
    reg = (reg << 8) | inverse_byte(data[i]);
```

need to be:

```
    top_byte = (uint8_t)(reg >> 24) ^ inverse_byte(data[i]);
    reg <<= 8;
```

and you need to delete these lines:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        top_byte = (uint8_t) (reg >> 24);
        reg = (reg << 8) ;
        reg ^= __crc32_table[top_byte];
    }
```

Then you get the right answer.

If you would like to implement the table approach on the augmented message as described in Chapter 9 (requiring another four iterations of the CRC at the end as in your code), then you need to first read these important notes in the document:

> Note: The initial register value for this algorithm must be the
> initial value of the register for the previous algorithm fed through
> the table four times. Note: The table is such that if the previous
> algorithm used 0, the new algorithm will too.

To get the same effect as the initial value of `0xffffffff` (notably *not* zero) with the non-augmented message version, which is how that standard CRC is defined, then you'd need to find an initial value such that applying 32 zero bits to it using the CRC gives you `0xffffffff`. That value is `0x46af6449`, obtained by reversing the CRC bit-wise algorithm:

```
    uint32_t x = -1;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        x = x & 1 ? ((x ^ 0x4c11db7) >> 1) | 0x80000000 : x >> 1;
```

Then your code will work if you fix the array size and the `toret` initialization errors, and simply replace:

```
    uint32_t reg = -1;
```

with:

```
    uint32_t reg = 0x46af6449;
```

Either augmented or not, reversing every single input byte as you are doing is a waste of time. You can and should instead just reverse the calculation and the polynomial. See rcgldr's answer.

Comment: You need to turn on your compiler warnings. The compiler will find several issues with your code, such as the lack of initialization.

Comment: Thank you :)

I just wanted to see how things work, not really do some optimizations, so I just kinda sticked with the polynomial and also with reversing.

So I guess the Chapter 9. is wrong in the painless guide? Because there is no XOR, but only OR:
   r=0;
   while (len--)
     {
      byte t = (r >> 24) & 0xFF;
      r = (r << 8) | *p++;
      r^=table[t];
     }

Comment: ... and also with that stuff with zero bytes:
for (i=0; i<W/8; i++) r = (r << 8) ^ t[(r >> 24) & 0xFF];

Comment: No, the painless guide is correct. I was one of the careful reviewers of that document. (25 years ago.)

Comment: Ow :) 

I would be very thankful, if you would point out where is the error then, I mean, If the pseudocode is correct, then where is the error in my code?

   while (len--)
     {
      byte t = (r >> 24) & 0xFF;
      r = (r << 8) | *p++;
      r^=table[t];
     }

for (i=0; i<W/8; i++) r = (r << 8) ^ t[(r >> 24) & 0xFF];

from that point I would try to achieve the optimal form (the one you suggested).

Comment: Can't subtract. _28_ years ago.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Wow! That's impressive! And I was going to give up on this one!

Thank you so much! I guess I need to spend more time on this stuff, and read more learning materials :) .

Answer (score 0):

Example code using right shifting CRC (0xedb88320 is a reflected version of 0x04C11DB7):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

uint32_t crctbl[256];

void gentbl(void)
{
uint32_t crc;
uint32_t c;
uint32_t i;
    for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
        crc = c;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            crc = (crc & 1) ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 : (crc >> 1);
        }
        crctbl[c] = crc;
    }
}

uint32_t crc32(uint8_t * bfr, size_t size)
{
uint32_t crc = 0xfffffffful;
    while(size--)
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crctbl[(crc & 0xff) ^ *bfr++];
    return(crc ^ 0xfffffffful);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
uint32_t crc;
uint8_t msg[10] = "123456789";

    gentbl();
    crc = crc32(msg, 9);
    std::cout << "crc " << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << crc << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). I'm rather interested to see how the algorithm works from a more simple level, rather than from fully optimized.

Comment: @foralost - it is using the same table method as the question's code. Reflected CRC's are typically implemented as right shifting CRCs in software. I didn't check all of the question's code, but one issue is data should XOR'ed to the CRC register before cycling the CRC register. Another is the CRC table needs to have a size of 256 entries, not 255. If I have time later, I'll try to include a fixed version of the question's code.

Comment: your code as I see uses the optimization, that we don't need to feed the register with extra zero bytes (solely Chapter 10.). My code does not use this, I simulate this by feeding the register with 4 zero input bytes (chapter 9., just shifting 8 bits). Also, the SIMPLE algorithm does not work wok with CRC32, but with CRC8 it works for some reason.

Yes, I forgot to change 255 -> 256, and in inverse func. I dont set the initial value.

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @foralost - This answer's code does not feed the register with extra zero bytes. It only loops through "size" data bytes, which in this example is 9 byte. The extra zero bytes are implied, but the code only needs to process "size" bytes without any further cycling of the CRC register.